# rails 3.1 mountable engines HTTP 404 Error on ajax post call

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jquery, ruby-on-rails-plugins, rails-engines

I am building my first Rails 3.1 engines plugin in which i have controller called initiatives_controller and have a action know as upload whenever i try to make a call to upload action via jquery ajax "post" call its returning me 404 error I feel there is some issue in routes.rb because it used work in Rails 3.0

My routes.rb looks like

```
Marcal::Engine.routes.draw do
   resources :media
   resources :initiatives
   post "initiatives/upload"
end
```

My initiatives_controller.rb

```
class InitiativesController < ApplicationController
   def upload
     puts "hiiiii"
     @medium = Medium.new(params[:medium])
     if @medium.save
        render :json => { 'status' => 'success' }
     else
        render :json => { 'status' => 'error' }
     end
  end
```

end
end

And i used do ajax call as below

```
          $.ajax({
            url: "/initiatives/upload",
            type: "POST",
            data: "medium=something"
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(sucessdata)
            {
              alert("success");
            }

         });
```

end

Answer (score 0):

Your dummy app is probably mounted on "/marcal" which is the default when you create a mountable engine. You're ajax probably doesn't simple because it sends the POST on "*/initiatives/upload*" instead of the desired "*/marcal/initiatives/upload*".

You might want to rename your javascript file from "name.js" to "name.js.erb" and change it's content to:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "<%= root_path %>initiatives/upload",
  type: "POST",
  data: "medium=something"
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(sucessdata)
  {
    alert("success");
  }
});
```

root_path is the key here.